# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Spyc' not found in app/code/DeviceDetector/Yaml/Spyc.php

Tags: php, magento, fatal-error, device-detection

I am facing the issue with **order placing on Magento ver. 2.2.2**. After complete the payment when I will redirect to website `https://domainname/paypal/express/placeOrder/` page and error display on that page.

```
Please check the error below,
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Spyc' not found in
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/Yaml/Spyc.php:17 Stack trace: #0
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/Parser/ParserAbstract.php(155):
>   DeviceDetector\Yaml\Spyc->parseFile('/p...') #1
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/Parser/ParserAbstract.php(243):
>   DeviceDetector\Parser\ParserAbstract->getRegexes() #2
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/Parser/Bot.php(53):
>   DeviceDetector\Parser\ParserAbstract->preMatchOverall() #3
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/DeviceDetector.php(623):
>   DeviceDetector\Parser\Bot->parse() #4
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/DeviceDetector.php(587):
>   DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector->parseBot() #5
>   /public_html/app/code/MageWorx/OrdersBase/Observer/OrderPlaced.php(107):
>   DeviceDetector\DeviceDetector->parse() #6
>   /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php(72):
>   MageWorx\OrdersBase\Observer\OrderPlaced- in
>   /public_html/app/code/DeviceDetector/Yaml/Spyc.php on line 17

The error is seems  related to the `DeviceDetector plugin` but I don’t know why this issue happen & I have check the particular lines mentioned in error but no solution found.

Please let  me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you add more details here, after what action this error start appear? 
If you inject this class somewhere in constructor then I suggest you to run `rm -rf generated/*` because M2 dont update generated folder automatically if you change class that already generated in generation.
If its not work please share some context.